# Derby Embedded Database on Readonly File Properties

Tags: java, netbeans, derby, readonly-attribute

Im using Java Netbeans 7.0 for my POS System , I already created an Installer or .exe of it using Derby Embedded database. 
My Problem is When im installing it to other PC in said that there is a problem on SQL database that is not permitted for a read Only connection,user and database.

Are there Possible Codes for Configuring the Read Only Properties for the directory file?

Comment: Can you include more details about the exact message you received?

Comment: Read the tag-descriptions before adding!